# Dagger 2 inject ViewModel odd behavior (ViewModel not re-used on screen rotation)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-lifecycle, dagger-2

I've noticed an odd behavior when injecting ViewModels into my activities/fragments (following the example at [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)).

**Trial 1** At first I was just lazily seeing what happens when I use

```
@Inject MainViewModel viewModel;
```

Obviously, I got a new instance of MainViewModel for every activity and when rotated.

**Trial 2**
I then updated to using "the right way" of injecting the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` and grabbing the view model in `onCreate`:

```
@Inject ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelProviderFactory;
private MainViewModel viewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelProviderFactory)
            .get(MainViewModel::class);
}
```

This snippet works like a charm. Printing the viewModel will show that I get a new instance for each new activity instance triggered from a startActivity call but re-using when rotated. This got me thinking... Maybe I can just inject the MainViewModel.

**Trial 3** I updated my MainActivityModule to include the following:

```
@Provides @ActivityScope
public MainViewModel provideMainViewModel(MainActivity activity,
        ViewModelProvider.Factory factory) {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(activity, factory).get(MainViewModel::class);
}
```

This resulted in a new instance of MainViewModel even on screen rotations (same as trial 1). I verified that the provided ViewModelProvider.Factory instance is the same every time that provideMainViewModel is called. I also tried removing the @ActivityScope which caused even stranger behavior especially when trying to include the same instance of MainViewModel in both MainActivity and MainFragment1. The fragment got the same instance of MainViewModel as before the rotation, but the activity got a brand new one, even though both calls to provideMainViewModel were called with the same instance of MainActivity and the factory.

**Question** Can anyone explain this? Is there no way for me to inject the ViewModel directly into my activity/fragment?

**UPDATE**

This is really baffling me so I've updated to include a full sample of the issue [HERE](https://github.com/yperess/android-architecture-components). Note that I've had to update AppInjector's `FragmentLifecycleCallback` to inject the fragment during `onFragmentPreCreated`. This was done due to the lifecycle of a fragment, the current implementation seen in `SearchFragment` using `SearchViewModel` will get the instance of the view model during `onActivityCreated` which may be called more than once on the same fragment. In such a case, the same view model will be returned from `ViewModelProviders` and multiple observers will be registered. Instead Fragments should be injected before `onCreate` and any LiveData observers should be registered at that point.

When run and rotated, you'll see the following logs:

```
12-19 22:48:28.538 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/MainActivityProvidersMo: provideMainViewModel for com.android.example.github.MainActivity@78c5d27 using com.android.example.github.viewmodel.GithubViewModelFactory@6d6c140: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@fd1f879
12-19 22:48:28.611 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/MainActivity: viewModel: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@fd1f879
12-19 22:48:28.615 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/dagger.android.support: An injector for com.android.example.github.ui.search.SearchFragment was found in com.android.example.github.MainActivity
12-19 22:48:28.616 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/SearchFragment: mainViewModel: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@fd1f879
12-19 22:48:28.760 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/SearchFragment: results live data has observers? false


12-19 22:48:40.579 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/MainActivityProvidersMo: provideMainViewModel for com.android.example.github.MainActivity@d1f344f using com.android.example.github.viewmodel.GithubViewModelFactory@6d6c140: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@c5387dc
12-19 22:48:40.581 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/dagger.android.support: An injector for com.android.example.github.ui.search.SearchFragment was found in com.android.example.github.MainActivity
12-19 22:48:40.583 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/SearchFragment: mainViewModel: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@c5387dc
12-19 22:48:40.625 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/MainActivity: viewModel: com.android.example.github.MainViewModel@c5387dc
12-19 22:48:40.715 7116-7116/com.android.example.github D/SearchFragment: results live data has observers? false
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but because the Factory is annotated at ActivityScope level, each new instance of the activity will have a different instance of the provider, which in turn will create a new instance of the view model. I would inject the Factory, annotate it at ApplicationScope (since we would like the retention), and then use it to get the instance of the view model.

Comment: The factory is using the `@Singleton` annotation (https://github.com/yperess/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java)

Comment: AFAIK Your MainActivityProvidersModule provides the ViewModel via the providers which are created (or reused) statically. As opposed to retrieving the factory itself, it seems like you're trying to get the best of both worlds, which just can't work with the way the system was created.
I would use the ViewModelProvidersOf pattern to get the factory, have it at ActivityScope, and then from it create the ViewModel